# Good Text for Learning about Multivariate Distributions

Tags: self-study, distributions, multivariate-analysis, references, multivariate-distribution

I have just started learning about multivariate distributions using Mathematical Statistics with Applications by Wackerly, Mendenhall and Scheaffer but I find their explanation a bit confusing, could someone please recommend a good text for learning about multivariate distributions?

Comment: Could you explain more about what's confusing? It might make it easier to suggest something that doesn't do the same.

Comment: Ideally I am looking at a book with simple explanations with plenty of examples, I find my current textbook a good resource for questions but I like plenty of examples to help me understand key concepts. I am fairly new to statistics so a slow pace would be Ideal.

Comment: Do you want to learn specifically about distributions or about how to do multivariate analysis?